# This manhwa is about a woman who is actually a demon, and got chased by an angel

Tags: story-identification, manga, webcomics

The protagonist lost her parents at a very young age. She has a male friend, this male friend has a little brother.

Someday, this friend died, and she has to take care of her friend's little brother. She grow up with this little brother until suddenly she found out that she is demon getting chased by an angel.

Her time living in the world is limited and she gets sick often because of her demon power. It turns out her friend's little brother was also demon in his past, and is related to her.

Comment: Do you remember about when you read this, and how many chapters it had at that time?

Answer (score 2):

I think the one you’re talking about is ***[Angel's Use](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/6nan8jy/how-to-use-an-angel)***.

> I was kidnapped by a bunch of crazy people who said they were going to summon a demon here in the 21st century. Fortunately, just when I was about to be sacrificed, a man with an "angel-like" face broke through the wall and appeared! ...But didn't you come here to save me? Why are you aiming your sword at me...?